# Как задать значение fixedRateString в Spring Scheduling из внешнего property файла

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Имеется Spring Boot Application с методом, который должен вызываться по определенному fixedRate.А так же property файл с настройками, который находится в следующей директории:

> ./config/bot/bot.properties.

Необходимо задавать интервал из этого property файла.
 Вычитал в документации что есть возможность задавать значение fixedRateString в таком виде:

```
@Scheduled(fixedRateString = "${${github.job.fixed.delay.seconds:60}000")
```

Но для меня остается непонятным, как это можно применить в моей ситуации.И можно ли указывать интервал не в формате cron, не в миллисекундах,а в минутах?

Comment: какие значения?

Comment: временной интервал, с которым будет запускаться метод

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Указать property файл можно путем добавления аннотации 
 
`@PropertySource("classpath:root/bot.properties")`  
И непосредственно в этом файле указать значение fixedRate в миллисекундах, либо же в формате cron.